# Combinations from a given set without repetition

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix defined as follows

```
M = [C1 C2 C3 C4]
```

Where the C's are column vectors
I want some efficient (i.e. no for loops) way of producing A vector such that

```
ResultVec = [C1 C2; 
             C1 C3; 
             C1 C4;
             C2 C3; 
             C2 C4; 
             C3 C4]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the simplest way I've come up with:

```
n = size(M, 2);
[j, i] = ind2sub([n n], find(~triu(ones(n))));
ResultVec = M(:, [i j]);
ResultVec = reshape(ResultVec, [], 2)
```

Answer (score 10):

That is, what `nchoosek` does:

```
M = [ 1 2 3 4 ];

R = nchoosek(M,2);
```

returns:

```
R =

     1     2
     1     3
     1     4
     2     3
     2     4
     3     4
```

I don't know if it's your intention but `nchoosek` is Matlabs implementation of ***The number of k-combinations from a given set S of n elements without repetition*** ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination))

The function `nchoosek` is performance wise not very efficient though. But there are equivalents on File Exchange, which are much(!!) faster and doing the same.

---

Just to make it clear, it's not just working for the fairly simple example above, and is not returning any indices. It directly transforms the matrix as desired.

```
M = [ 21 42 123 17 ];
```

returns:

```
R =

    21    42
    21   123
    21    17
    42   123
    42    17
   123    17
```

Comment: Good to know about this use of `nchoosek`! I stole it for an update of my answer...

Comment: @A.Donda I don't get what you need the other lines for? `nchoosek` is absolutely everything you need.

Comment: The question was about arranging the columns of a matrix `M`. What you provided are just the indices used to do so. What you get is `R = [1 2; ...`, what he wants is `R = [C1, C2; ...`, where `C1 = M(:, 1)` etc.

Comment: @A.Donda that's not true. If `M = [ 21 42 123 17 ];` it works also.

Comment: True, I didn't notice. It does not, however, work for `M = [ 21 42 123 17 ; 1 2 3 4 ];`.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you by adopting your `nchoosek`. If you'd like, I can remove it from my answer. But still, my answer works for the general case that the poster asked for, and yours doesn't. Moreover, your answer didn't really explain that `nchoosek` does more than produce indices.

Comment: @A.Donda Don't worry I'm not offended at all, I just don't see the necessity of your further steps ;) I'll improve my answer a bit. `nchoosek` has nothing to do with indices, it is just matlabs implementation for [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)