# Access to row i of a specific matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to access to row `i` of `A=nchoosek(1:m,n)`. This command of MATLAB is very time consuming, specially for large `m`. So, I do not want to construct whole of `A`. I want to build just row`i` of `A`.

Although, it seems that my question is duplicate of "[Combinations from a given set without repetition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426957/combinations-from-a-given-set-without-repetition)", but they are different.

That answer did not cover different columns. It is just get acceptable results for `A = nchoosek(M,2)`. I want to find `A (i,:)`, where `A= nchoosek(1:m,n)`, for given `i`, `m`, and `n`.

Comment: Now I don't understand your question. What is `i` supposed to do?

Comment: `A=nchoosek ( 1:n, m)`. I want to access to `A ( : , i )`, without using `nchoosek`

Comment: Tried to understand your third line, there was some typo in it. Fixed it.

Comment: @Meher81: Is the order of a relevant or would some code returning `sort(A)` solve it as well?

Answer (score 1):

**This answer answers the original version of the question, not the updated version**

This is exactly what nchoosek does, when you input a vector.

```
nchoosek([1:n],m)
```

.

```
>> m=2

m =

     2

>> n=5

n =

     5

>> nchoosek([1:n],m)

ans =

     1     2
     1     3
     1     4
     1     5
     2     3
     2     4
     2     5
     3     4
     3     5
     4     5
```

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to use `nchoosek([1:n],m)`. In my real code, n could be very large. As, depends on m and n, I need just one column of `A=nchoosek([1:n],m)`, I want to construct the desire vector in a different way. Using `nchoosek([1:n],m)`  for large `n` is very time consuming, and require a lot of memory.

Comment: @Meher81: Please update your question and explain what you really want. Your question says you want `A` and not just one column of `A`